# ArcGIS Desktop 9.3 conflict with Internet Explorer on Windows XP?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, installation, internet-explorer

I have been told that ArcGIS Desktop 9.3 will not function on a Windows XP computer if its got Internet Explorer newer than version 6.

Is this true?

Seems like a huge security hole if you can only have IE 6 on your computer.

If so, how can this be fixed?

Comment: I remember this from a while back but can't find the NIM number. I believe it was resolved. Also note that on Win XP you cannot install IE9 (only works for W7) so you can install up to IE8.

Comment: SaultDon: How is it resolved? Via an update from ESRI? Thanks.

Comment: I cannot find the specific NIM still, but there may now be [another browser conflict](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/37827-Firefox-version-6-and-ArcGIS-failure) for some users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have one machine running 9.3 with IE8.  Version 10 runs with no problems with IE8 or IE9.  Perhaps it is a rumour, or an old one.